# R officer constructing set_header_labels lists of column names and replacements

Tags: r, officer

The officer set_header_labels function assigns a name to print replacing the column name, like this.

```
ft <- set_header_labels(ft,
```

values = list(
Sepal.Length = "Sepal length",
Sepal.Width = "Sepal width",
Petal.Length = "Petal length",
Petal.Width = "Petal width"
)

I'd like to construct the pair of column name and replace dynamically. For example I have

```
cols_names <- c("colname1", "colnametitle1")
cols_titles <- c("colname2", "colnametitle2")
```

I want these to be output as

values = list(
colname1 = "colnametitle1",
colname2 = "colnametitle1"
)

This gets close for the column names and titles pairs

```
paste0(cols_names, ' = "', cols_titles, '", "' )
```

But there must be some easier way manipulating lists that I haven't figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `paste0` will not work as the `values` argument of `set_header_labels` requires a named `list`. But you could use `setNames` to do so.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `iris`:

```
library(flextable)

dat <- head(iris[1:2])
names(dat) <- c("colname1", "colname2")

ft <- flextable(dat)

cols_names <- c("colname1", "colname2")
cols_titles <- c("columntitle1", "columntitle2")

values <- setNames(cols_titles, cols_names)

ft <- set_header_labels(ft,
  values = values
)

ft
```

[image]